# Where can I download a dodecahedron Photoshop template?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to add images to a template, print it out, and make an origami dodecahedron shape. Where can I download a dodecahedron Photoshop template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd personally recommend Illustrator for this, as you'll be printing it. There's a PDF download at http://www.korthalsaltes.com/model.php?name_en=dodecahedron which you may well be able to import into Illustrator to edit. One way or the other, though, you'll be able to open it in photoshop at whichever resolution you require.